# how java find real path of dependency jar file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

how java find real path of dependency jar files?

Comment: please elaborte more, because it is unclear what you really ask and what is the exact problem you try to solve.

Comment: how java find real path of dependency JAR archives?